# Importing GitHub projects to BitBucket wont finish

Tags: github, import, bitbucket

I used the BitBucket option to import three projects from GitHub (Repositories -> Import -> Import from GitHub). However, only one of the three projects finished, the other two are now being imported for the last three days, while showing this screen. As you might guess, nothing happens appart from the animation of a cosmetic progress bar.

[image: Infinite import screen]

I'd just give it another try but unfortunately, the process cannot be aborted. Has anyone had a similar problem before?

Comment: Refreshing the page doesn't abort the process?

Comment: @cricket_007: no, im afraid not...

Comment: This is likely something you should direct to Bitbucket support.

Comment: @wehnsdaefflae Similar issues have indeed occur, you need to ask bitbucket support team to delete the repository. That will stop the process. Then you can try again, typically it works after that. I believe they are still searching the reason for this behavior.